# javascript closer and returning objects

Tags: javascript, module

I'm trying to create this simple Toaster function that will create a new toaster and return an object of the type and how it was cooked. A pretty straight forward exercise except I am getting an error of 'Uncaught ReferenceError: typeOfFood is not defined'. I am trying to pass typeOfFood as the parameter. Here is the code:

```
var Toaster = function(){  
function cook(type,temp){ 
    var food = type;
    var amtCooked; 
    if(temp >7){
    amtCooked = "Well Done!"
    }else if(temp > 4){
    amtCooked = "Medium";
    }else{
    amtCooked = "Lightly done!";
    }
    this[food] =food + amtCooked;
}
return{
toast: function(typeOfFood,setting){
        cook(typeOfFood,setting)
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: inner function `cook` is called with parameters `typeOfFood, settings`, but they are not defined in outer function's scope (`toast`) and they are not passed as arguments into it

Comment: Yes that was an overlook on my part, i forgot to add those but I had it in there before but removed it when trying things.  I am trying to get it to set a new property as the typeOfFood with value of setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
var Toaster = function(){  
function cook(type,temp){ 
    var food = type;
    var amtCooked; 
    if(temp >7){
    amtCooked = "Well Done!"
    }else if(temp > 4){
    amtCooked = "Medium";
    }else{
    amtCooked = "Lightly done!";
    }
    this[food] =food + amtCooked;
}
return{
toast: function(typeOfFood,setting){
        cook(typeOfFood,setting)
        }
    };
}
```

*Reason:* You are returning the function toast, so when you create an object and call toast you need to send arguments here and need to receive in function `toast`

To call:

```
var v = new Toaster();
v.toast("bread",4)
```

**No ERROR** now

If you don't want to give paramenters in toast function then, you can use `arguments` object of `toast` function do this way:

```
 var Toaster = function(){  
    function cook(type,temp){ 
        var food = type;
        var amtCooked; 
        if(temp >7){
        amtCooked = "Well Done!"
        }else if(temp > 4){
        amtCooked = "Medium";
        }else{
        amtCooked = "Lightly done!";
        }
        this[food] =food + amtCooked;
    }
    return{
    toast: function(){
            cook(arguments[0],arguments[1])
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: How can I get it to set the property of the object as the 'typeOfFood' argument? It doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: I am trying to get it to set a new property as the typeOfFood with value of setting.

Comment: You want an object with property as typeOfFood and amdCooked. or you want an array with  typeOfFood and amdCooked as two entries or you want a string with concatenated message?

Comment: I would just like it to add the property to the toaster object